# Can an export map select only the functions you want to link to?

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile, gnu

I am writing a test harness with Googletest and need to control the symbol table to avoid conflicts (the code base is mainly C with a bit of C++ on Linux).

I am looking for a way to link against only the functions I want in a file and also to be able to create custom sets of functions to link against for each test.

This is a bit broad I know but any suggestions or ideas will be most welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a version script for your linker to define, which symbols should be exported in the symbol table.

Such a version script can look like this:

```
{
  global: 
    symb1;
    symb2;
    symb3;
  local: *;
};
```

This example will only export the symbols symb1-3, all other symbols are omitted from the symbol table.

Now specify this script as version script for the linker, an example for a shared library:

```
cc -shared obj1.o obj2.o obj3.o -o library.so -Wl,--version-script=<scriptname>
```

Even more control can be gained through symbol versions, more details can be found in the ld-documentation: http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_25.html